# Python KeyError Dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, missing-data, keyerror

- I have a list, called tweets_data
- Each element of the list is a dictionary
- Keys of the dictionary is 'text'
- But the raw data has some missing 'text'

That is why, I want to remove the dictionaries having missing text.
This is how my code looks like:

```
for i in range(len(tweets_data)):
    try:
        print tweets_data[i]['text']
    except KeyError:
        tweets_data.remove(tweets_data[i])
        i += 1
```

And I am receiving such an error:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

My question:
Is it possible to just remove the missing data from my list with a more clever way so that I won't get such an error?
Thanks ahead!

Comment: Do you know what the error means?

Comment: You can't remove items from a list while you're iterating over it without confusing the indexes! Each time you remove, the list gets shorter - but you're still counting up to the length of the original list and expecting to find elements there.

Comment: @Ben is that still the case when iterating over a range? not over the list itself

Comment: The problem is that the `range` matches the original `list`, but it's being applied to a shrinking `list`.

Comment: Yes - because for a 10-element list, you'll still be trying to find element at index 9, even if you've deleted half the list - so you'd get an IndexError.

Comment: But, without removing the item, how can I make my code just skip the dictionary having missing text... Otherwise, I am getting KeyError because of missing key. I am stuck

Comment: See my answer - should give you exactly what you need. If it does, feel free to accept it with the tick.

Answer (score 2):

You can't remove items from a list while you're iterating over it without confusing the indexes. Each time you remove, the list gets shorter - but you're still counting up to the length of the original list and expecting to find elements there.

Try this instead:

```
ok_tweets = [x for x in tweets_data if 'text' in x]
```

Answer (score 0):

Might suit you to have a different approach

```
new_tweet_data = [tweet for tweet in tweet_data if 'text' in tweet]
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this one works...

```
cleandata=[]
for i in range(len(tweets_data)):
    try:
        print tweets_data[i]['text']
        cleandata.append(tweets_data[i]['text'])
    except KeyError:
        i += 1
```

Comment: @ Tim, sorry to make you edit my code all the time.. I don't know how to make it.. Thanks though..

Answer (score 0):

<strike>If your data is of reasonable size I'd recommend a filtered list comprehension, as previously suggested by others</strike>

```
filtered = [tweet for tweet in tweets_data if 'text' in tweet]
```

OTOH, if your list is LARGE and the defective items, those you want to remove, are just a few, it is possible that an approach based on `.remove()` may be faster, avoiding the intermediate step of creating a LARGE new list

```
delenda = [defective for defective in tweet_data if 'text' not in defective]
for tweet in delenda: tweeets_data.remove(tweet)
```

Beware that each `.remove()` has to scan the whole list, so this approach could be competitive only for a very small ratio of items to remove

If you need to deliver a product based on this question I heartily recommend timing the different approaches with samples of your data

Having read https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity, *in species*

> Internally, a list is represented as an array; the largest costs come from growing beyond the current allocation size (because everything must move), or from inserting or deleting somewhere near the beginning (because everything after that must move).

I have striked  out my previous answer, suggesting the use of `.remove()` to avoid copying a possibly LARGE list, because it turns out  that every `.remove()` is, in effect, COPYING a possibly large part of the list.

The right thing to do is indeed a list comprehension.